# Adding a view to a view just crashes the android application

Tags: javascript, view, appcelerator

I'm using Kevin Whinnery's Snapost application for reference (https://github.com/kwhinnery/Snapost/blob/master/1.1.x/Snapost/Resources/app.js), but when add a view to a view the application just crashes.

This is the only code i have in the application.

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#FFF'); 

var viewContainer = Titanium.UI.createView({
    top:0,
    width:320,
    height:420 
});

var home = Titanium.UI.createView({
      top:0,
      width:320,
      height:420,
});

viewContainer.add(home);

var app = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:"main window"
});    
app.add(viewContainer);
app.open();
```

Comment: what platform is this on iOS or Android? I just pasted this code in a new project and it works fine

Comment: sorry cant help... i dont mess with 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with API 1.6, it works fine on API 2.2.